# Since a few days, no rep changes occur "in green", not getting pinged

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, top-bar

Feels like a silly question, but someone please shine a brilliant light on this: Since a few days, none of the rep changes occurred "in green" on any of my devices, (so not) like this:

[image]

just the number changes. Also missing many of the pings. It happened to me occasionally in the past, which made me shrug, since it was only occasionally. Seems all the time now.

Devices:

- Desktop box Ubuntu 18.10 / Firefox 67.0
- Laptop Ubuntu 19.04 / Firefox 67.0
- Android 6.0 Phone / Chrome 74.0.3729.157

What could be the cause?

---

### EDIT

No clue what caused it but after a short period of this if I tried to reach AU:

[image]

I saw these again.

[image]

...Back to work...

Comment: Since only SE can help, please treat this as a bug report. What devices? What browser(s)? What operating systems? I happen to have read the discussion you had about this in chat, but if I hadn't, I would have had no idea what "in green" was referring to. Perhaps a screenshot would help.

Comment: When you lose reputation, you usually don't get notified until you pass the level you were previously at. This seems to work a bit inconsistently, but could be the explanation

Comment: @Zanna I think the reason it may seem inconsistent is that viewing your achievement pane resets the negative to zero and starts showing the rep increases again... I think. So... you lose a bunch of rep, miss a few upvotes, check your achievements, see the upvotes, upvotes start coming in again. If you hadn't checked the achievements, they wouldn't have shown up until the rep equalized.

Comment: @Catija thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few days ago you lost a sizeable chunk of rep due to a user being removed. [See May 25th](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm?tab=reputation). When you lose reputation, due to downvotes or vote reversals of any sort, we don't show you reputation increases again until your reputation earnings have exceeded your reputation loss. This is because we show your *net* reputation change and we do not show negative numbers.

So, if your reputation drops 200 points, you have to earn 201 reputation before you see that first green +1 icon on the achievements trophy.

The alternate way to start seeing your reputation changes in this case is to check your achievements by clicking on the trophy in the top bar. This will zero out your current running total and all new upvotes will again be visible.

For the most part we all actually do this regularly (with the exception of people who like to see big green numbers). You see a +20, click on the trophy to see which posts were upvoted and the +20 disappears. The difference here is that the +20 just turns the -200 into -180, which we still aren't going to show you. But, much as we clear the +20, we clear the unseen -180, so that next upvote does what you'd expect; +10.

[The Firefox error is unrelated.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328820/is-anybody-else-having-pki-problems-connecting-using-firefox-67-0) I'm guessing that at some point you clicked on the trophy icon to see why you weren't being notified which cleared your tally and made the numbers start showing up again.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! never thought of that!